# Pytorch Sigmoid Function what is e

Tags: pytorch, sigmoid

I have a question on setting up the sigmoid function in pytroch.

So I define it as this

```
# Sigmoid function
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1 + torch.exp(-x))
```

But then looking at the sigmoid function from here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SigmoidFunction.html

The sigmoid should be defined as

```
y = 1/(1 + e^-x)
```

I see the 1/(1+  part but I don't get the e^-x part. Can someone explain why

```
torch.exp(-x) == e^-x
```

What is e here? Is that the tensor. But i thought that x was the tensor

Comment: e is a mathematical constant see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)). e^x is basically mathematical syntactic sugar for the exp(x) function but they mean the same thing.

Comment: so your are saying the exp() is e here? Is that what .exp(-x) does

Comment: x is just a variable so exp(<something>) = e^<something> its just a different representation of the same thing.

Comment: Seeing you were first could you make your explanation the answer and I will accept it. Thank you @jodag

Comment: It's fine go ahead and accept Dishin's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here `e` is the exponential constant e and 
`torch.exp(-x) == e^-x`

- [torch.exp(x)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.exp) returns e^x

Comment: so the parameter that you plug into will be x correct. So e does not have to be defined.